# Excel Formula separate the left numeric values from the data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have some data in Col"K" where from i am just trying to get the left characters as i tried in Col"H" using formula.

But what i used is Left function like =Function(cell,10) that is not the correct way characters can be more than 10 or less than 10.

1st formula should be dynamic to get the left numeric values.
2nd Formula should copy and paste the same numeric values until next value comes as available in Col"I"

I tried to make it but what i can do is to create left function and do not know how to develop it dynamic.

Any help will be appreciated.

Sheet Link
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nJZeWDZ0EWgmWB0z17xU93fjIOFsu46EL37IJqJzZ_0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: If it is on Excel then best approach is to use `Filterxml()` function.

Comment: Yes i tried it with FilterXML but could not make it @Harun24HR

Comment: Give me access to google doc and let me try.

Comment: Sure please @Harun24HR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This formula should do the job.

```
[J2] =IFERROR(TRIM(LEFT(L2,FIND("-",L2)-1)),J1)
```

Note that it will fail if placed in row 1 and there is no dash in L1.

Comment: "Not working accurate" isn't a useful description of your complaint, and it makes even less sense after you accepted an answer that's an exact copy from mine - and then embellished it with the same useless remark. I think the formula is working but perhaps not in Google sheets. Your question expressly wants an **Excel** formula. Are you testing it in Excel or Google?

Comment: apologies for the inappropriate comments. But in both Excel and google sheets formula has same problem.

Comment: Thank you for selecting my answer although it doesn't help you.

Comment: Actually i did not see the answered hours you were first who answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use **find** function to get numeric characters length.

```
=iferror(trim(left(L3,FIND("-",L3)-1)),M2)
```

Here we are finding the separator **"-"** in your text and it gives us index number of separator.
Then picking text from start to before index number i.e., Numeric value and removing blank spaces, if any, using **trim** function. If we don't have number/separator in the text then showing previous cell value using **iferror** function. So, Make sure first row always has numeric value.

Same has implemented in the sheet you have shared

**As per the latest data I have updated my answer as below , now it is checking output is numeric or not:**

```
=IF(COUNT(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},J9))=0,K8,TRIM(LEFT(J9,FIND("-",J9)-1)))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but your formula is not working accurate if you check that thing in sheet. @Samsani Hymavathi

Comment: Not able to access the sheet now. Please provide the access I will check again. As far as I remember, I have checked my results with your results column and all were matching.

Comment: I have updated please have a look @Samsani Hymavathi

Comment: I have updated the answer, please check and confirm

Comment: Thank you @Samsani Hymavathi its working now.