# Formula which separates the numeri values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have been using below formula which works as separator but it works for those data which has numeric value.

I just want that which data has not that values like `03931_0000` then formula should copy paste the above value when its not find new value in the range.

I have been trying but its very much complicated i have attached below sheet where `Col"K"` has data and `Col"I"` has the result which i want by the formula and `Col"G"` has my formula.

```
=IFERROR(TRIM(LEFT(K9,FIND(" - ",K9)-1)),G8)
```

help towards the problem will be appreciated.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nJZeWDZ0EWgmWB0z17xU93fjIOFsu46EL37IJqJzZ_0/edit#gid=2097555068

Comment: Why is this different to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66071836/9758194) question you asked earlier? If not, than it's a copy and should be closed.

Comment: Sir, @JvdV i have marked as answer but it does not fulfill the requirements accordingly i have tried to change it alot to make it work but nothing happens\.

Comment: Then why mark an answer and open a new question? As is, this is just a copy of your previous question.

Comment: Because the data i have pasted on the sheet earlier was dummy and this formula was working accurate on the dummy data, but not on original data.

Comment: Why are you using `D8` in your formula? D8 seems to be an empty cell ?

Comment: that was G8 @Luuk changed the columns and forgot to change D8 to G8 but still formula has the same problem.

Comment: So, you have asked this question earlier, and marked it as having a correct answer. Then you re-asked the same question and you still have "the same problem" ???  Please re-read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Yes sure @Luuk thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the formula that will work in Excel.

[J2]=IF(ISERROR(VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(K2,FIND(" ",K2) -1),"_",""))),J1,LEFT(K2,FIND(" ",K2) -1))